# What's the pair correlation function? What information does it contain?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, radial-distribution-function, correlation-functions

This question is related to this [VASP tutorial](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Liquid_Si_-_Standard_MD), in which the pair correlation function (or radial distribution function: RDF) is utilized to justify whether the solid silicon is melt by AIMD (ab-initio molecular dynamics) or not.

How is the RDF defined and what information can we obtain from it?

[image: Pair correlation function of melting silicon]

[image: Radial distribution function for Copper-zinc system]

Comment: Related question on Chem SE: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136463/why-do-the-peaks-in-a-radial-distribution-function-graph-have-a-probability-1/136510#136510

Comment: Related unanswered: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6480/how-to-calculate-radial-distribution-functions-for-md-trajectories-without-pbc

Comment: It may help if you clarify what additional information you are looking for beyond what is in the linked Chem SE question and other questions with radial-distribution-function tag.

Comment: Ben-Naim gives the best explanation I have ever seen. Both from a probability stand points, and a physical standpoint

Comment: @B.Kelly Do you want to help us clear this from the unanswered queue then? :)

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.